# LINQ OrderBy sort Problem

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a LINQ Query:

```
bikersList = (From c In ngBikersDataContext.Reg_Bikers _
                        Order By c.L_Name _
                        Select New Bikers() With { _
                        .BikerID = c.BikerID, _
                        .F_Name = c.F_Name, _
                        .M_Name = c.M_Name, _
                        .L_Name = c.L_Name, _
                        .MyID = c.MyID, _
                        .Site = c.Site.GetValueOrDefault, _
                        .bk_Building = c.bk_Building, _
                        .bk_City = c.bk_City, _
                        .bk_Zip = c.bk_Zip.GetValueOrDefault, _
                        .bk_Phone = c.bk_phone, _
                        .email = c.email, _
                        .DeptZone = c.DeptZone, _
                        .QuartID = c.QuartID.GetValueOrDefault, _
                        .BikerDays = c.BikerDays.GetValueOrDefault, _
                        .BikerMiles = c.BikerMiles.GetValueOrDefault, _
                        .BikerTime = c.BikerTime.GetValueOrDefault, _
                        .BKLockID = c.BKLockID.GetValueOrDefault, _
                        .bk_Start_DT = c.bk_Start_DT, _
                        .bk_End_DT = c.bk_End_DT, _
                        .bk_Quarter = c.bk_Quarter.GetValueOrDefault, _
                        .bk_Year = c.bk_Year.GetValueOrDefault, _
                        .bk_Comments = c.bk_Comments, _
                        .IsActive = c.IsActive.GetValueOrDefault _
                        }).ToList()
```

This works great and sorts on L_Name. But I am trying to allow the user to sort the gridview themselves. So I am passing in the SortExpression as a string. But I don't know how to incorperate the SortExpression into the LINQ Query.

I tried

```
Order By c. & SortExpression
```

But that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out something called a Dynamic Query in Linq.

[Using the LINQ Dynamic Query Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Comment: I would like to use the Dynamic Library but I do not know how to implement it into my project. Can you give me a step by step on how to do this?

Comment: there are a few examples on that link above. is there a specific problem you're having with dLINQ, or is it a DLL / reference problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article that talks about dynamic sorting with linq using a sortexpression string:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Generic_Sorting.aspx

Basically, you'll need to build the expression tree manually.

(this code is from the link above)

```
Public Function Sort(ByVal source As IEnumerable(Of T), _
                     ByVal sortBy As String, _
                     ByVal sortDirection As String) As IEnumerable(Of T)

    Dim param = Expression.Parameter(GetType(T), "item")

    Dim sortExpression = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of T, Object))_
    (Expression.Convert(Expression.[Property](param, sortBy), _
    GetType(Object)), param)

    Select Case sortDirection.ToLower
        Case "asc"
            Return source.AsQueryable().OrderBy(sortExpression)
        Case Else
            Return source.AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(sortExpression)
    End Select

End Function
```